# Showcase view on first launch of react native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have been looking for a guide to create a showcase view on first launch of my react native app, I might don't know the correct word for it, actually it's a user guide for features on first launch, it has a direction towards the icon and it's details, I haven't found anything on it, it'll be a great help if anyone guide me about that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo code from the doc of react-navigation. I think it's similar to your case.

```
if (state.isLoading) {
  // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
  return <SplashScreen />;
}

return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {state.userToken == null ? (
      // No token found, user isn't signed in
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignInScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Sign in',
          // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
          // You can remove this if you want the default 'push' animation
          animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      // User is signed in
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Add a firstLaunch state to true first and then set it to false and save in the asyncstorage.Something like:

```
  let firstLauch = await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstLauch");
  firstLauch = JSON.parse(firstLauch);
  firstLauch = firstLauch === false?firstLauch:true
  let [isFirstLauch,setIsFirstLauch]=useState(firstLauch);

return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {isFirstLauch ? (
      // No token found, user isn't signed in
      <Stack.Screen
        name="FirstLauch"
        component={FirstLauchScreen}
      />
    ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Don't forget to set firstLauch to false in your firstLauchScreen.

Comment: I think he meant to have something similar to this: https://github.com/dragfire/react-native-showcase-view  On first launch, it guides user where to click, have a tutorial for what each button does etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the popular npm package for creating your showcase of first launch https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-copilot

Comment: Is there a version for web?

Comment: It should be as it is in vanilla javascript, You can have a try.